# Best way to generate pdf output from gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, plotting

I have many data files in a directory. Each data file has various columns and I want vector plots using a few of them. Earlier I was generating .png files using a .gp script and combining them into a movie. I need outputs in PDF format also for showing in presentation and including in articles. The png script is:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set xla 'x'
set yla 'y'
scl=3
do for [i=0:10000:200]{
    set output sprintf('vector_frame%04.0f.png',i)
    plot 'data.'.i.'.dat' u 3:4:($5/scl):($6/scl) w vec ti sprintf("frame %d",i)
    set output
```

The resolution of png images is much poorer than that of the qt terminal and the plots are often not of much help. The pdf outputs from pdfcairo are also not good. In addition, there are situations where I have to `set size ratio 2'. There the *labels on the x-axis overlap*. The code and a sample output are given blow.

```
set terminal pngcairo
set xla 'x'
set yla 'y'
set size ratio 2
scl=3
set output 'pngeg.png'
plot 'data.2000.dat' u 3:4:($5/scl):($6/scl) w vec
```

[image: png output from pngcairo]

I want to know what is the best way to save gnuplot vector plots in a form which is closest to the qt output and of good resolution. I need to do thousands of such plots in multiple directories. So a *script* to do the same would be very helpful.

I require outputs in **PDF** format. However, can pdf files be combined to make a movie or animation? Otherwise, I would need png images also.

I am new to gnuplot and some detailed advice would be a saviour. Thank you.

Comment: Try `set terminal pdf`. Read (in `gnuplot`): `help set output`.

Comment: have done that, the output is of lower resolution than qt terminal.